# mdbootstrap lightbox not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I am using mdbootstrap lightbox code to open up lightbox on click.
Code is very simple but for some reason it is not working.
Here is my code.
I am using CDN links/urls so anyone can test it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Material Design Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.4/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div id="mdb-lightbox-ui"></div>

            <div class="mdb-lightbox no-margin">

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(117).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(117).jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(98).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(98).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(131).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(131).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(123).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(123).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(118).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(118).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(128).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(128).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(132).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(132).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(115).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(115).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(133).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(133).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.4/js/mdb.min.js"></script>


    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->

    <script>
    // MDB Lightbox Init
    $(function () {
        $("#mdb-lightbox-ui").load("mdb-addons/mdb-lightbox-ui.html");
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

When I click on the image it do not show the light box as need it.
I am not sure what is going wrong.Anybody like to check.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Lightbox is a premium component of MDBootstrap. It means you cannot use it with MDB Free

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a paid version and after purchasing it from mdbootstrap you will get required files/folders.

Updated code :
On the other hand 
I have done some research on it and I am able to find the possible solution to make it work.

It is bit tricky.
mdb-addons/mdb-lightbox-ui.html 
Path must be correct and exact.

For testing purpose : You can download it from here 
https://github.com/rushijeware/testGitHub/blob/master/mproj10/src/main/webapp/assets/mdb-addons/mdb-lightbox-ui.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Material Design Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.4/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



    <link rel='stylesheet' id='compiled.css-css' href='https://mdbootstrap.com/wp-content/themes/mdbootstrap4/css/compiled-4.5.7.min.css?ver=4.5.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div id="mdb-lightbox-ui"></div>

            <div class="mdb-lightbox no-margin">

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(117).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(117).jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(98).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(98).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(131).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(131).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(123).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(123).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(118).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(118).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(128).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(128).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(132).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(132).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(115).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(115).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

                <figure class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/12-col/img%20(133).jpg" data-size="1600x1067">
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(133).jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                    </a>
                </figure>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.js"></script>

    <script>
 // MDB Lightbox Init
 $(function () {
      $("#mdb-lightbox-ui").load("mdb-addons/mdb-lightbox-ui.html");
 });
  </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Follow the above page structure and add required JS/CSS to so it will start working easily.
I hope it help someone !